# Symfony Propel Query

Tags: symfony1, propel

I want to make this query on Symfony/Propel

```
SELECT 
folders.NAME,
COUNT(documents.NAME),
COUNT(files.idfiles),
SUM(files.size)

FROM  `folders`
LEFT JOIN `documents_has_folders` ON (documents_has_folders.folders_idfolders = folders.idfolders)
LEFT JOIN documents ON (documents_has_folders.DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS=documents.IDDOCUMENTS) 
LEFT JOIN files ON (documents.IDDOCUMENTS=files.DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS) 

GROUP BY folders.idfolders
```

I do this query

```
$x = FoldersQuery::create()
            ->addSelectColumn(FoldersPeer::NAME)
            ->addSelectColumn("COUNT(".DocumentsPeer::IDDOCUMENTS.")")
            ->addSelectColumn("COUNT(".FilesPeer::IDFILES.")")
            ->addSelectColumn("SUM(".FilesPeer::SIZE.")")
            ->addJoin(DocumentsHasFoldersPeer::FOLDERS_IDFOLDERS, FoldersPeer::IDFOLDERS, CRITERIA::LEFT_JOIN)
            ->addJoin(DocumentsHasFoldersPeer::DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS, DocumentsPeer::IDDOCUMENTS, CRITERIA::LEFT_JOIN)
            ->addJoin(DocumentsPeer::IDDOCUMENTS, FilesPeer::DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS, CRITERIA::LEFT_JOIN)
            ->addGroupByColumn(FoldersPeer::IDFOLDERS)
            ->find();
```

This returns:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | PropelException
Unable to execute SELECT statement [SELECT folders.NAME, COUNT(documents.IDDOCUMENTS), COUNT(files.IDFILES), SUM(files.SIZE) FROM LEFT JOIN folders ON (documents_has_folders.FOLDERS_IDFOLDERS=folders.IDFOLDERS) LEFT JOIN documents ON (documents_has_folders.DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS=documents.IDDOCUMENTS) LEFT JOIN files ON (documents.IDDOCUMENTS=files.DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS) WHERE folders.REMOVE_DATE IS NULL GROUP BY folders.IDFOLDERS] [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN folders ON (documents_has_folders.FOLDERS_IDFOLDERS=folders.IDFOLDERS)' at line 1]
```

Why there is no table on FROM??? Why it creates a wrong query?

Thanks a lot.

EDITED:

Same problem have and if i do the query like this:

```
$c = new Criteria();
    $c->addSelectColumn(FoldersPeer::NAME);
    $c->addSelectColumn("COUNT(".DocumentsPeer::IDDOCUMENTS.")");
    $c->addSelectColumn("COUNT(".FilesPeer::IDFILES.")");
    $c->addSelectColumn("SUM(".FilesPeer::SIZE.")");

    $c->addJoin(DocumentsHasFoldersPeer::FOLDERS_IDFOLDERS, FoldersPeer::IDFOLDERS, CRITERIA::LEFT_JOIN);
    $c->addJoin(DocumentsHasFoldersPeer::DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS, DocumentsPeer::IDDOCUMENTS, CRITERIA::LEFT_JOIN);
    $c->addJoin(DocumentsPeer::IDDOCUMENTS, FilesPeer::DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS, CRITERIA::LEFT_JOIN);

    $c->addGroupByColumn(FoldersPeer::IDFOLDERS);
```

Again after FROM there is no table...

```
Unable to execute SELECT statement [SELECT folders.NAME, COUNT(documents.IDDOCUMENTS), COUNT(files.IDFILES), SUM(files.SIZE) FROM LEFT JOIN folders ON (documents_has_folders.FOLDERS_IDFOLDERS=folders.IDFOLDERS AND folders.remove_date IS NULL ) LEFT JOIN documents ON (documents_has_folders.DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS=documents.IDDOCUMENTS AND documents.remove_date IS NULL ) LEFT JOIN files ON (documents.IDDOCUMENTS=files.DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS AND documents.remove_date IS NULL AND files.remove_date IS NULL ) WHERE folders.remove_date IS NULL AND documents.remove_date IS NULL AND files.remove_date IS NULL GROUP BY folders.IDFOLDERS] [wrapped: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN folders ON (documents_has_folders.FOLDERS_IDFOLDERS=folders.IDFOLDERS ' at line 1]
```

Comment: Is the FROM clause sill empty, if you do a very simple query such as `$x = FoldersQuery::create()->limit(10)->find();` ?

Comment: it returns correct data and the query is right if i do 

$x = FoldersQuery::create()->limit(10)->find();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the Propel way to build queries since Propel 1.6 (maybe before). We don't use Criteria nor Peer classes. The following query:

```
SELECT 
folders.NAME,
COUNT(documents.NAME),
COUNT(files.idfiles),
SUM(files.size)

FROM  `folders`
LEFT JOIN `documents_has_folders` ON (documents_has_folders.folders_idfolders = folders.idfolders)
LEFT JOIN documents ON (documents_has_folders.DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS=documents.IDDOCUMENTS) 
LEFT JOIN files ON (documents.IDDOCUMENTS=files.DOCUMENTS_IDDOCUMENTS)
```

Can be written like that:

```
$query = FoldersQuery::create())
    ->joinDocuments('documents')
    ->joinFiles('files')
    ->withColumn('COUNT(documents.NAME)', 'CountName')
    ->withColumn('COUNT(files.IDFILES)', 'CountIdFiles')
    ->withColumn('SUM(files.size)', 'Sum')
    ->select(array('Name', 'CountName', 'CountIdFiles', 'Sum'))
    ;
```

It may requires adjustments but it's the right way.

Comment: The query you give me dont work... i have manytomany realtionship from table 1 to table 2 and from table 2 to table 3 1 to many. how to join all these 4 tables?

Comment: @user783029 - "don't work" isn't sufficient to describe what problem you're having. As William says, it may require adjustments - it is better for the learning process if you try to make some. If that doesn't work, tell us what errors you're getting, or what is different between expectation and output :)

Comment: is it possible achieve the functionality NOT using the new way of creating queries in Porpel 1.6? I have bulk load load of elder code using the old Criteria-type querying, Frankly, some them are working, some of them are not. I bet this is kind of a bug in the codebase.